# Enzyme React setTimeout related testing causing errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I want to test whether a method is called after a certain time interval in a React component using enzyme and sinon-mocha.

**React Component**

```
var TestComp = React.createClass({
    myFunc: function() {
        console.log('I am called');
    }
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.timer = window.setTimeout(myFunc, 2000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
})
```

**Unit Test**

```
var clock;

before(function () {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

after(function () {
    clock.restore();
});

it('myFunc is called once', function() {
    spy(TestComp.prototype, 'myFunc');

    var wrapper = mount(<TestComp/>);

    clock.tick(3000);

    expect(TestComp.prototype.myFunc.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
});
```

**Error**

It throws assertion error. The test is crashing at the timing event, which I identified using some console logs on the wrapper node. It says stack trace error. However, the the test case triggers `myFunc`, which is evident from the console log.

How can I capture the `myFunc` call?
Does anyone know why it happens?

The console error is same as this https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/87#issuecomment-8547823

**Update**

StackTrace:

```
'Error: Stack Trace for original
at Object.wrapMethod
at spy
at Context.<anonymous>
at callFn
at Test.Runnable.run
at Runner.runTest
at next
at Immediate.<anonymous>
at Immediate.<anonymous>
at runCallback
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]
restore: { [Function] sinon: true } } and in between all filename locations.
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error text?

Comment: stackTrace: 'Error: Stack Trace for original\n    at Object.wrapMethod
 at spy,  at Context.<anonymous>  at callFn   at Test.Runnable.run  at Runner.runTest  at next  at Immediate.<anonymous>  at Immediate.<anonymous> at runCallback  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]  restore: { [Function] sinon: true } } and in between all filename locations.

Comment: What version of sinon.js do you use?

Comment: The version no. >> v1.17.5